# Linear Transformations, Function Composition

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Considering the transformations

$\ f:\Re^{2} \rightarrow \Re^{2}$ and  $ g:\Re^{2} \rightarrow \Re^{2}$
 defined by

$f(a,b)= (0,b)$, for any $(a,b) \in \Re^{2}$

and

$g(a,b)=(a,a)$, for any $(a,b) \in \Re^{2}$

Justify that $0$ = $f \circ g$ $\neq$ $g \circ f$

$0$ is the null transformation of $\Re^{2}$

My Resolution:

First I worked out $(f \circ g)$:

$(f \circ g)(a,b)$ = $f(g(a,b))$ = $f(a,a) = (0,0)$

Then I worked out $(g \circ f)(a,b)=g(f(a,b))=g(0,b)=(0,0)???$

What am I dong wrong?

Comment: $f(a,a)\neq(0,0)$

Comment: Also, $g(0,b)\neq (0,0)$.

Answer (score 1):

$gf(a,b)=g(f(a,b))=g((0,b))=(0,0)$.
$fg(a,b)=f(g(a,b))=f((a,a))=(0,a)$.
So we have $gf=0$ but $gf\ne fg$. Perhaps the problem intended to say "Justify $0=gf\ne fg.$"

Comment: It says "Justify $0=f \circ g \neq g \circ f$" and it's on the composite function section.

Comment: Well then that's simply incorrect. For example, take $(1,0)$, then $g(1,0)=(1,1)$ and $f(1,1)=(0,1)\ne(0,0)$ so $fg\ne0$.

Comment: If you have $f(a,a)=(0,a)=(0,0)$, since   $  a=0?$